# RegEx for fail2ban not matching for nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, fail2ban

I need some help with my conf for fail2ban on nginx. Logfile entries I want to block look like this:

```
21/Nov/2017:11:41:27 +0100 107.204.xxx.xxx - - mydomain.com "HEAD http://84.200.xxx.xxx:80/phpmyadmin2011/ HTTP/1.1" 401 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee" "-"
```

My filter is this in a 401.conf:

```
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 401 0 *
```

But I get the following output from fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/401.conf:

## Results

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [3395] Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 3395 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 3395 missed
Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 3395 lines

Although the log has several lines that should match... any ideas?

Thx for helping me out, 'cause I'm pretty new to RegEx.

Comment: [use something like this when developing regular expressions](https://regexr.com/) and remove `^<HOST>` because none of your lines start with "<HOST>".

Comment: Did you intend to have a period before the apostrophe at the end of your regex?

Comment: @castis this is needed by fail2ban to identify which ips to ban.

Comment: It looks like you meant to have a period in your expression before the very last asterisk, so that it matches more characters after 401 0